# How to parse the phrase: "attention-deficit/hyperactivity disorder"

Tags: grammaticality, speech

I am trying to figure out what this phrase deconstructs to.

Does it imply a logical OR, like: "attention-deficit disorder" OR "hyperactivity disorder"?

---

For additional context, there are different types mentioned [here](https://www.psychiatry.org/patients-families/adhd/what-is-adhd):

> There are three main types of ADHD:
>
> - Predominantly inattentive presentation.
> - Predominantly hyperactive/impulsive presentation.
> - Combined presentation.

...which seems to indicate that it is always both, but a little more of one than the other.

If this is the case, does the grammar check out?

Also when it is spoken as: "attention deficit hyperactivity disorder", or abbreviated as "ADHD", the slash is dropped, which loses meaning and adds confusion.

Would there be a better way to phrase it? Would there be a better way to say it?

Comment: Blame it on the slash, an all-purpose cowardly mark to say A, B, AB, none of the above, and all of the above. Not logical but so what? The reader is left to sort it out.

Comment: *Would there be a better way to phrase it? Would there be a better way to say it?* This is too vague to be answerable. Obviously there are longer and more precise ways of expressing it, and shorter and less precise ways. So what are your criteria for finding a better way? Regardless, it's off-topic as both an opinion-based question, and a question that's looking for a new name for something rather than asking about existing usage.

Comment: It might be better to direct this question to those who study such disorders. They know (or should know) why this label has been chosen and whether reformulating it in this or that way would distort its meaning. The 'grammar' does 'check out', because slash, by its nature allows a great deal of vagueness (as Mr. Baskin has already observed).

Comment: What are you really Asking, please?

How could anyone think either that 'attention-deficit/hyperactivity disorder' meant the same as 'Attention deficit hyperactivity disorder (ADHD)' or that either term was a 'phrase'?

Is it not obvious that 'attention-deficit/hyperactivity disorder' is a mistake and 'Attention deficit hyperactivity disorder (ADHD)' is not a 'phrase' but a technical term; if you like, a name?

Answer (score -1):

https://www.psychiatry.org/patients-families/adhd/what-is-adhd

There are three main types of ADHD:

- Predominantly inattentive presentation.
- Predominantly  hyperactive/impulsive presentation.
- Combined presentation.

You're not really meant to parse such abbreviations or names/captions as if they were statements. This one is a label for a disorder marked by symptoms that are often but not always combined.

Comment: Only the last two sentences offer an answer to the question. It s not clear what the point is of repeating what is already in the question.

Comment: When I was younger they typically referred to ADD and hyperactivity independently. Eventually they determined that they were related along a spectrum, and combined the terms into ADHD.

Comment: @Barmar  combined in the late eighties,  IIRC.

Comment: @Barmar: I was working around that time for a company that provided counseling services and the DSM was a frequent topic of conversation.

Comment: @Tim I mainly know about this because when I was a teenager in the 70's I had a cousin who was hyperactive, and I don't remember anyone using the term ADD or ADHD at the time in reference to him.

Comment: @Barmar ADD entered DSM-III around 1980.